# MSCRM: Can one convert a CrmService to a DataContext (new CRM SDK)?

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm

I'm trying to create a DataContext (a class available via the new MSCRM SDK) from an existing CrmService. Is this at all possible in a supported manner?

If so, how can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you talking about a LINQ DataContext?  If so, this isn't openly supported.  You could create the Linq to SQL scaffolding just like with any other database and then have access to a DataContext, but updates/inserts would be unsupported.

There are some [third party tools](http://www.xrmlinq.com/) that allow you [to use LINQ](http://linqtocrm.codeplex.com/) to do queries.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. :(

Are those 3rd party tools "supported" by MS?

Answer (score 0):

The [Advanced Developer Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff681559.aspx) (part of the most recent SDK release) provide an [XrmDataContext class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff681573.aspx) to allow querying CRM via linq.